# What range of mismatch can the internal tuner on the TS-480SAT accommodate?

Tags: antenna-tuner, kenwood

A fellow ham recently acquired a [TS-480SAT](http://www.kenwood.com/i/products/info/amateur/ts_480/). His working condition is complemented by an inverted-vee for the 20m band around 10m above ground; solid 59+ reports. Trying to tune the same antenna on other bands using the in-built tuner fails outright.

I'm curious; what range of mismatch can the internal tuner on the 480SAT accommodate?

Answer (score 1):

Oddly, the range is not mentioned in the manual.  Discussion about the feature on the web seems to agree that it's limited to a 3:1 match.  That's sounds right as that is a pretty common figure for internal tuners from other manufacturers.

If you can borrow him an SWR meter to test the unit, he could verify that figure empirically pretty easily.

Comment: Ah. Right. I forgot to mention we looked for it in the manual ... /+: There isn't a meter at hand

Comment: Yeah, well, it's safe to say the match is worse than 3:1 if the tuner fails.  That antenna should tune up on 40m at better than 3:1 unless it's really low to the ground.